# How can I fill a Matrix row by row

Tags: c#

So I have this problem:

> A person has `N` shops in a city. Write a console app which receives from input:
>
> - on the first line, `N`
> - next `N` lines, each of them containing the profit of every shops for each of the year trimesters, with 2 decimals precision. Numbers are separated by one space.
>
> Output :
>
> - most profitable trimester;
> - most profitable shop;
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> 2
> 1000.50 2000.00 1000.00 3000.00
> 500.00 600.00 700.00 800.00
> ```
>
> Result:
> Trimester 4 : 3800.00 Shop 1 : 7000.50

Now about my question... I've written some code, but I don't know how to fill the matrix row by row. Here is my code:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int numberOfTrimesters = 4;
        int numberOfShops = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        double[,] shopsList = new double[numberOfShops, numberOfTrimesters];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfShops; i++)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] array = input.Split(' ');
            double[] shop = new double[array.Length];
            for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
                shop[j] = Convert.ToDouble(array[j]);
            for (int k = 0; k < numberOfShops; k++)
                for (int m = 0; m < numberOfTrimesters; m++)
                    shopsList[k, m] = shop[array.Length];
        }
```

The problem is on last line of the last `for`.

Comment: You can get rid of `shop` and the second inner `for` loop and, in the first inner loop, just do `shopList[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(array[j]);`

Comment: As arrays are zero-indexed, valid elements of shop are `shop[0]`, `shop[1]`, ... `shop[shop.Length-1]`.  Since shop.Length == array.Length `shop[array.Length]` will always be out of bounds.  And if it were not it would always be the same element.

Comment: Thank you so much @Camilo Terevinto. It works

Comment: Yeah I know that @IceGlasses. But I had written that because I wanted to highlight where I had the problem.

Comment: No problem :) you're on the right track by the way